# disqus universal code with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views, disqus

I'm working on backbone website that uses disqus as its commenting system, I use backbone boilerplate, and I registered a module for the comment, I included in it the js provided by DISQUS

my module looks like this :

```
define([
'namespace',
'use!backbone'
], function(namespace, Backbone) {

var Comment = namespace.module();

Comment.Views.CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "app/tpl/comment/main.html",
    render: function(done) {
        var view = this;
        namespace.fetchTemplate(this.template, function(tmpl) {
            view.el.innerHTML = tmpl();
            if (_.isFunction(done)) {
                done(view.el);
            }
        });
    },
    commentScript: function() {
        console.log('Comment Script INIT.');
        var disqus_identifier = 'a unique identifier for each page where Disqus is present';
        var disqus_title = 'a unique title for each page where Disqus is present';
        var disqus_url = 'a unique URL for each page where Disqus is present';
        var disqus_developer = 1;
        var disqus_shortname = 'dandin95'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script');
            dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
            dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';

            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    }
});

return Comment;

});
```

my main.html only contain a div with id 'disqus_thread' that used view the comment box

My issue is : when rendering my view nothing done and chrome console shows 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of null         embed.js:65

when adding this script to the template every thing working well.

Any advice ????

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it looks like you are creating a backbone view to initialize and render the DISQUS widget within the #disqus_thread DIV and then re-render based on the state of the page:

```
define('disqus', [], function(){

    var disqus_shortname = DISQUS_SHORTNAME,
        disqus_identifer = INDEX_IDENT,
        disqus_title = DISCOVERY_TITLE,
        disqus_url = URL_HERE,
        disqus_developer = '1';  // could be deprecated?

    var DisqusView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#disqus_thread',
        initialize: function() {
            // DISQUS universal code:
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        },

        render: function(options) {

            DISQUS.reset({
                options: options,
                reload: true,
                config: function(){
                    this.page.identifer = options.identifer;
                    this.page.title = options.title;
                }
            });

        }
    });

    var disqusView = new DisqusView();

    return disqusView;
});
```

OK! so lets make the assumption that the #disqus_thread element already exists on the page (hence setting `el`). When the module is loaded, DISQUS will do the initialization.

Say an event is fired off that requires the loading of a new Disqus thread:

```
$('.article_title').on('click', function(e) {
    var $post = $(e.target).attr('id');
    disqus.render({
        identifier: $post,  // OR however you decide to determine these attributes
        title: $post
    });
});
```

The iFrame within the #disqus_thread element will then be reloaded to the proper thread. This is a very thinly layered example, but imagine calling `disqus.render({...})` within an events hash or router.

[DISQUS Ajax Reset Snippet](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/snippets/js/disqus_reset.html)